# How improve performance when join pyspark Dataframes

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-performance

I have 2 pyspark Dataframess, the first one contain `~500.000 rows` and the second contain `~300.000 rows`. I did 2 join, in the second join will take cell by cell from the second dataframe (300.000 rows) and compare it with all the cells in the first dataframe (500.000 rows).

So, there's is very slow join. I broadcasted the dataframes before join.

Test 1:

```
df_join = df1.join(F.broadcast(df2), df1.String.contains(df2["search.subString"]), "left")
```

The job took many hours to finish.

Test 2:

```
df_join = F.broadcast(df1).join(F.broadcast(df2), df1.String.contains(df2["search.subString"]), "left")
```

The running is very slow than the first code above, so the performance is very bad.

I tried `to cache the dataframes` before join.

I used:

`df.cache()` for each dataframe. But, the performance always not good.

I tried to use `persist in memory_only`:

```
df.persist(MEMORY_ONLY) ==> NameError: global name 'MEMORY_ONLY' is not defined
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) ==> NameError: global name 'StorageLevel' is not defined
```

How can I persist the Dataframe in memory ?

Can you please suggest me a solution to improve the performance ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import StorageLevel` , you'd have to import the module

Comment: A regex type join will always be very slow. Can you not merge it in python?

Comment: @samkart I already added it but I got the error: ImportError: cannot import name StorageLevel

Comment: Ah! I think it should be `from pyspark import StorageLevel`

Comment: @samkart Hi, do you have some idea about this issue please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931770/sum-of-column-values-pyspark
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

df=df.cache()

print(df.count())

Basically, you need to call an action to get the effect of caching.