# Sum of array elements depending on value condition pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe:

```
id   |   column
------------------------------
1    |  [0.2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0.5]
------------------------------
2    |  [7, 0.3, 0.3, 8, 2,]
------------------------------
```

I would like to create a 3 columns:

- `Column 1`: contain the sum of the elements < 2
- `Column 2`: contain the sum of the elements > 2
- `Column 3`: contain the sum of the elements = 2 (some times I have duplicate values so I do their sum) In case if I don't have a
  values I put null.

Expect result:

```
id   |   column               |  column<2 |  column>2   | column=2 
------------------------------|--------------------------------------------  
1    |  [0.2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0.5]|  [0.7]    |  [12]       |  null
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    |  [7, 0.3, 0.3, 8, 2,]  | [0.6]     |  [15]       |  [2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you help me please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use [`aggregate`](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) and [`filter`](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) higher-order functions like this:

```
df.withColumn("column<2", expr("aggregate(filter(column, x -> x < 2), 0D, (x, acc) -> acc + x)")) \
  .withColumn("column>2", expr("aggregate(filter(column, x -> x > 2), 0D, (x, acc) -> acc + x)")) \
  .withColumn("column=2", expr("aggregate(filter(column, x -> x == 2), 0D, (x, acc) -> acc + x)")) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Gives:

```
+---+------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|id |column                        |column<2|column>2|column=2|
+---+------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|1  |[0.2, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.5]|0.7     |10.0    |2.0     |
|2  |[7.0, 0.3, 0.3, 8.0, 2.0]     |0.6     |15.0    |2.0     |
+---+------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way you can try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# using map filter the list and count based on condition
s = (df
     .select('column')
     .rdd
     .map(lambda x: [[i for i in x.column if i < 2], 
                     [i for i in x.column if i > 2], 
                     [i for i in x.column if i == 2]])
     .map(lambda x: [Row(round(sum(i), 2)) for i in x]))
     .toDF(['col<2','col>2','col=2'])

# create a dummy id so we can join both data frames
df = df.withColumn('mid', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
s = s.withColumn('mid', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

#simple left join
df = df.join(s, on='mid').drop('mid').show()

+---+--------------------+-----+------+-----+
| id|              column|col<2| col>2|col=2|
+---+--------------------+-----+------+-----+
|  0|[0.2, 2.0, 3.0, 4...|[0.7]|[10.0]|[2.0]|
|  1|[7.0, 0.3, 0.3, 8...|[0.6]|[15.0]|[2.0]|
+---+--------------------+-----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) function and do the calculation in one step:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# I adjusted the 2nd array-item in id=1 from 2.0 to 2.1 so there is no `2.0` when id=1
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,[0.2, 2.1, 3., 4., 3., 0.5]),(2,[7., 0.3, 0.3, 8., 2.,])],['id','column'])

df.withColumn('data', expr("""

    aggregate(
      /* ArrayType argument */
      column,
      /* zero: set empty array to initialize acc */
      array(),
      /* merge: iterate through `column` and reduce based on the values of y and the array indices of acc */
      (acc, y) ->
        CASE
          WHEN y < 2.0 THEN array(IFNULL(acc[0],0) + y, acc[1], acc[2])
          WHEN y > 2.0 THEN array(acc[0], IFNULL(acc[1],0) + y, acc[2])
                       ELSE array(acc[0], acc[1], IFNULL(acc[2],0) + y)
        END,
      /* finish: to convert the array into a named_struct */
      acc -> (acc[0] as `column<2`, acc[1] as `column>2`, acc[2] as `column=2`)
    )

""")).selectExpr('id', 'data.*').show()
#+---+--------+--------+--------+
#| id|column<2|column>2|column=2|
#+---+--------+--------+--------+
#|  1|     0.7|    12.1|    null|
#|  2|     0.6|    15.0|     2.0|
#+---+--------+--------+--------+
```

Before Spark 2.4, the functional-support for ArrayType is limited, you might do it with explode and then groupby+pivot:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as fsum, expr

df.selectExpr('id', 'explode_outer(column) as item') \
  .withColumn('g', expr('if(item < 2, "column<2", if(item > 2, "column>2", "column=2"))')) \
  .groupby('id') \
  .pivot('g', ["column<2", "column>2", "column=2"]) \
  .agg(fsum('item')) \
  .show()
#+---+--------+--------+--------+                                                
#| id|column<2|column>2|column=2|
#+---+--------+--------+--------+
#|  1|     0.7|    12.1|    null|
#|  2|     0.6|    15.0|     2.0|
#+---+--------+--------+--------+
```

In case `explode` is slow (i.e. [SPARK-21657](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657) shown before Spark 2.3), use an UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("column>2", DoubleType()), 
    StructField("column<2", DoubleType()),
    StructField("column=2", DoubleType())
])

def split_data(arr):
   d = {}
   if arr is None: arr = []
   for y in arr:
     if y > 2:
       d['column>2'] = d.get('column>2',0) + y
     elif y < 2:
       d['column<2'] = d.get('column<2',0) + y
     else:
       d['column=2'] = d.get('column=2',0) + y
   return d

udf_split_data = udf(split_data, schema)

df.withColumn('data', udf_split_data('column')).selectExpr('id', 'data.*').show()
```

Comment: Nice the `aggregate` with only one iteration (+1). One can set the zero value with `array(0D, 0D, 0D)` to avoid checking for nulls.

Comment: @jxc It worked well, Thanks a lot for your very good solution, but it was late a little bit, there's other solution published before 
Thanks :)

Comment: @blackbishop, you should not use `array(0D, 0D, 0D)` in initializing zero_value if you want to set NULL value on the absence of a condition.